# MySQL PHP Order From Another Table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a question.

I have 2 tables, one includes the comments and the other one includes the votes of these comments.

> my comments table:

```
--------------------
comment_id | comment
     1        abc1
     2        abc2
     3        abc3
     4        abc4
--------------------
```

> my voting table:

```
------------------
user_id  comment_id | voted
    1          1         1  // comment 1 has the result +1 now
    2          1         1  // comment 1 has the result +2 now
    3          1         2  // comment 1 has the result +1 now
    4          4         1  // comment 4 has the result +1 now
    5          4         2  // comment 4 has the result 0 now
------------------
```

Well, if a person *likes* a comment, it is saved as "1" to "voted". If a person *dislikes* a comment, it is saved as "2" to "voted".

```
$likes = $db->query('SELECT * FROM voting WHERE voted=1')->num_rows;
$dislikes = $db->query('SELECT * FROM voting WHERE voted=2')->num_rows;
$the_result = $likes-$dislikes;
```

For example, When 5 people liked a comment and 2 people disliked the same comment, the result I show is "+3".

I want to sort them using the greatest result.

Like: the first comment to show will have +4, the second one to show will have +2, the third one to show will have -2.

I want to do this in PHP. Thanks for helping.

Sorry for my bad explanation, this is my first question here. :(

Comment: Is there anything that you have tried yet? Any code?

Comment: and what is your question?

Comment: I couldn't think of any solutions, yet.

Comment: My question is: I want to sort comments using the results. I want to show the most liked comment at the top of the page for example.

Comment: If `1` is for "like" and `2` is for "dislike" then how do you get any negative values at all?  How do five `1`s and two `2`s add up to `3`?  Are votes recorded in their own rows, or are you always updating the same row?  It's not really clear how your data is structured.

Comment: To sort your results you just need SQL `GROUP BY column_name` by default it will give you lowest number first so you can sort them using the greatest result by sorting in descending instead of ascending order like `GROUP BY column_name DESC`

Comment: why aren't you simply keeping track of the likes inside the first table? Why two? If a comment has likes, why not put them together? then you could just do a `SELECT * FROM comments ORDER BY voted DESC`

Comment: @David I use num_rows to get the likes and the dislikes of a comment.

Comment: I see what you mean now @Todd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try the following:

```
SELECT *, 
    (count(CASE WHEN vote = 1 then 1 ELSE NULL END) - (count(CASE WHEN vote = 2 then 1 ELSE NULL END))) as RESULT 
FROM comments AS c
LEFT JOIN votes as v ON c.comment_id=v.comment_id
GROUP BY c.id
ORDER BY RESULT desc
```

Comment: I believe this is correct but i can't get it worked. Why :/

Comment: "mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given." Can't I use it with mysqli_fetch_assoc ?

Comment: you shouldnt be getting that error. Can you show the code you are using?

Comment: another boolean. please help me. i need to get this worked :\

Comment: Do you have Teamviewer? maybe I can assist you remotely.

Comment: $q = $db->query("SELECT *, (count(CASE WHEN vote = 1 then 1 ELSE NULL END) - (count(CASE WHEN vote = 2 then 1 ELSE NULL END))) as RESULT  FROM comments AS c JOIN votes as v ON c.comment_id=v.comment_id GROUP BY c.id ORDER BY RESULT desc");
while($ss = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)){
  // my codes
}

Comment: OK I'll download the programme

Answer (score 1):

Counting the votes:

> Return only comment_id and the total votes:
>   [Check the code](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fd860/11/0)

```
SELECT comment_id, SUM(
  CASE voted 
    WHEN 1 THEN 1 
    ELSE -1
   END) AS total 
FROM voting 
GROUP BY comment_id
ORDER BY total DESC;
```

> Return with comments that has votes: [Check the code](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fd860/12/0)

```
SELECT comment_id, comments, SUM(
  CASE voted 
    WHEN 1 THEN 1 
    ELSE -1
   END) AS total 
FROM voting
INNER JOIN comments 
  USING(comment_id)
GROUP BY comment_id
ORDER BY total DESC;
```

> Return all rows: [Check the code](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fd860/15/0)

```
SELECT comment_id, comments, SUM(
  CASE voted 
    WHEN 1 THEN 1 
    ELSE -1
   END) AS total 
FROM voting
RIGHT JOIN comments 
  USING(comment_id)
GROUP BY comment_id
ORDER BY total DESC;
```

Comment: I didn't define "voted". I just get the "likes" then "dislikes" and I use math "likes-dislikes" to get the result.

Comment: As I've said, the system saves as "1" to voted if someone likes a comment. And the system saves "2" to voted if someone dislikes a comment.

Comment: And I use "$db->query('SELECT * FROM voting WHERE voted=1')->num_rows" and "$db->query('SELECT * FROM voting WHERE voted=2')->num_rows"

Comment: @SeçkinPoyraz Your are not counting all the votes at one column. What I understood is that each user vote you insert a new row identifying if it's like or dislike vote.

Comment: @ThiagoAugustOliveira Yes! That's what I'm doing.

Comment: @ThiagoAugustOliveira Why didn't yo use the table "comments"?